# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined at Object.execute - Fixing needed

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to mute the system, but the console sent me this error TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined at Object.execute

Then my bot crashed. I tried to delete some of the code, but the bot continued crashing for the same thing. I tried to delete "cache" but the error changed to

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined at Object.execute

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const ms = require('ms')
const db = require("megadb")
const muterol = new db.crearDB("muterol")

module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    alias: [ ],
  
  async execute (client, message, args){

    var perms = message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")
    if(!perms) return message.channel.send("No tienes permisos suficientes para usar ese comando!")

    let time = args[1]
    if(!time) return message.channel.send("Debes decir un tiempo!")
    let timer = ms(time)

    let mencionado = message.mentions.users.first()
    if(!mencionado) return message.channel.send("Debes mencionar a alguien!")

    var razon = args[2]
    if(!razon) {
        razon = 'No especificado'
    }

    if(muterol.tiene(message.guild.id)) return message.channel.send("Este servidor no tiene ningún rol para mutear")

    let rol = await muterol.obtener(message.guild.id)

    if (mencionado.roles.cache.has(rol)) return message.channel.send("Ese usuario ya estaba muteado!")

    mencionado.roles.add(rol)

    await setTimeout(async function() {

        await mencionado.roles.remove(rol)

        await message.channel.send(`Se acabo el tiempo de mute de ${mencionado}`).catch(error => {message.channel.send(`Hubo un error inesperado! **${error}**`)
        })

    }, timer)
 
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the variable `mencionado` refers to a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), rather than a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

`User`s do not have the `.roles` property (thus why `User.roles.cache` results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache'...`

To fix this, you need to use [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) rather than [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users):

```js
...
let mencionado = message.mentions.members.first();
...
if (mencionado.roles.cache.has(rol)) return message.channel.send("Ese usuario ya estaba muteado!");
...
```

Another thing to note is that if this command is run in a [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel), it will also crash your bot.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the variable `mencionado` refers to a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), rather than a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

`User` is not a member and therefore cannot have a `roles` property

To fix this, you need to use [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) rather than [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users):

```js
let mencionado = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Another thing to note is that if this command is run in a [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel), it will throw an error as a dm channel does not have members and therfore does not have roles.